# Why doesn't Visual Studio create an APK when building a Xamarin Forms app?

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms

I'm using Visual Studio 16.2 Enterprise.

When I build my Xamarin Forms app the .apk file isn't created.
However when I deploy the app to the device the .apk is created at that point.
This means that when our build server does a release build, there's no .apk created.

I have the deploy option checked in the configuration manager for both debug and release builds.

Is there a way to ensure the .apk is created?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your devops, you can add:

```
<AndroidBuildApplicationPackage>true</AndroidBuildApplicationPackage>
```

to your csproj (only works for RELEASE configurations).

source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/xamarin/android/deploy-test/building-apps/build-process

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the archive process [found in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/release-prep/?tabs=windows#archive) to build the APK file.

Comment: If I use the Archive menu option the .apk is created, similarly to if I used Deploy.  However that's still a manual step.